# Embedding image in preview UIView while capturing photo with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

While implementing `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate`'s method `didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer` I'm trying to fill the `previewView` with the image after it is captured. So later on if the user is not happy with the image, there will be another button which will trigger the `previewView` to start showing preview to handle the image capture. Here is how far I could get:

```
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {

    if let error = error {
        print("Error capturing photo: \(error)")
    } else {
        if let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer, let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer, let dataImage = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {

            if let image = UIImage(data: dataImage) {

                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(previewView.frame.size)
                image.draw(in: previewView.bounds)

                if let imageToEmbed: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                    self.previewView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: imageToEmbed)
                } else {
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                    print("image not available")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As shown above I'm using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` but not able to set the `previewView` to be the image just captured. How can this be achieved? Thank you.

Comment: Add UIImageView to previewView and set an image to it instead of drawing the image.

Comment: @ninjaproger that solution worked for me. Thank you.